# Demonstration of the Brans-Dicke's Lagrangian

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

The Lagrangian in general relativity is written in the following form:
$$
\begin {aligned}
\mathcal {L} & = \frac {1} {2} g ^ {\mu \nu} \nabla_{\mu} \phi \nabla_{\nu} \phi-V (\phi) \\
& = R + \frac {16 \pi G} {c ^ {4}} \mathcal {L} _ {\mathcal {M}}
\end {aligned}
$$

with $g^{\mu\nu}: $ the metric

$ \phi: $ non-gravitational scalar field

$ R $: Ricci scalar

$ \mathcal {L} _ {\mathcal {M}}: $ Lagrangian of the density of matter

By replacing the gravitational constant $ G $ by its new definition, $\dfrac {1} {\varphi (t)}, $ **How can I prove that the Lagrangian within the framework of Brans-Dicke becomes :**

$$
\mathcal {L} = \varphi R + \frac {16 \pi} {c ^ {4}} \mathcal {L} _ {\mathcal {M}} - \omega_ {BD} \left (\frac {\varphi_{, i} \varphi ^ {, i}} {\varphi} \right)
$$

?

Any track/clue/help is welcome

Comment: Are you asking how the $\frac {\varphi_ {, i} \varphi ^ {, i}} {\varphi}$ term arises?

Comment: @NiharKarve . Yes, I talk about this term which appears magically.

Comment: Considering we promote $1/G$ to a scalar field, it is natural to provide it with a kinetic term

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some preliminary consideration:
In a uniform expanding universe the gravitational potential fulfills in atomic units the equation

$$\frac{GM}{R} \propto 1$$

with $c=1$ and $R$ is the reciprocal Hubble parameter and $M$ the total mass of the visible universe. Now the assumption of Brans was that not only the geometry defines gravitation, but also the mass. So the gravitational constant should be depending on the mass. When you write this equation like

$$ \phi= \frac{1}{G} \propto \frac{M}{R} \propto \sum_i \frac{m_i}{r_i}$$

you can interpret this as $G$ depending on the contribution of all matter to the inertial reaction. Here $G$ is assumed to be a function of $\phi$ so that the variation of both quantities is assumed to be equal. Then you get a roughly equal equation to that one above when assuming a inhomogeneous wave equation

$$ \square \phi \propto \rho$$

with a scalar mass density $\rho$. The concept of this kind of wave equation is that the quantity on the right hand side describes a so called source function. These source functions describes the effect of the sources, here the mass, on the medium carrying the waves. This approach arises from the implementation of Machs principle which leads to the assumption that not only the geometry of the Rieman manifold, but also the mass have an effect on the gravitation.

Outgoing from the Einstein Lagrangian

$$\mathcal{L} = R + \frac{16\pi G}{c^4} \mathcal{L}_{\mathcal{M}},$$

the approach is to replace the gravitational constant by the scalar field $\phi$. For that the Einstein Lagrangian is multiplied by $G^{-1}=\phi$:

\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}_{\text{JBD}} :&= \frac{\mathcal{L}}{G} = \frac{R}{G} + \frac{16\pi}{c^4} \mathcal{L}_{\mathcal{M}} \\
&= R \phi + \frac{16\pi}{c^4} \mathcal{L}_{\mathcal{M}}.
\end{align}

Because of the previous considerations we want a wave equation for $\phi$. So we add a term $\mathcal{L}_\phi \propto \phi_\mu \phi^\mu$:

$$\mathcal{L}_{\text{JBD}}=R \phi + \frac{16\pi}{c^4} \mathcal{L}_{\mathcal{M}} + \mathcal{L}_{\phi}(\phi, \phi_\mu).$$

Because of unit consistency you can show that $\mathcal{L}_\phi$ has to be second order in space-time and first order in $\phi$. The $\phi$ in the denominator of $\mathcal{L}_\phi$ arises, because in physics the coupling constants describing the strength of fundamental forces are chosen dimensionless. Because $\omega$ describes a coupling between the mass and the scalar field this quantity should also be dimensionless. With these assumptions you should be able to verify the desired equation. Keep in mind that $\omega$ is only a dimensionless constant without further meaning in this derivation.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Unfortunately, I don't understand very well how you add and under which conditions the term $\mathcal{L}_{\phi}(\phi, \phi_\mu)$. Moreover, in a first time, you talk about the Lagrangian, and after, you talk about the Lagrangian density. So for all of this, could you detail a little more your reasoning ?, I make confusions for the moment. Best regards

Comment: I've reworked my answer. I hope it is more understandable now.

Comment: Thanks for your reworking. 1) Why do we write $\square \phi \propto \rho$ ? Indeed, a wave equation should be written as : $\square \phi=0$. 2) Moreover, I don't understand why you write $\mathcal{L}_\phi \propto \phi_\mu \phi^\mu$ whereas thre is, in my initial formula, the term : $- \omega_ {BD} \left (\frac {\varphi_ {, i} \varphi ^ {, i}} {\varphi} \right)$, could you detail please ?

Comment: In short a wave equation that not equals zero is called an inhomogenous wave equation. To your second question the reasoning for this choice of the Lagrangian is that you want $\omega$ to be a dimensionless constant. I will discuss this further in a rework of the answer later this day.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know the concept of inhomogenous wave equation and its characteristics. It's fine from your part to detail latter your answer.

Comment: "The $\phi$ in the denominator of $\mathcal{L}_\phi$ arises, because in physics the coupling constants describing the strength of fundamental forces are chosen dimensionless" - could you clarify on this?

Comment: To clarify this. The coupling constants doesn't have to be chose dimensionless. In QFT the motivation for this choice arises due to renormalization problems. But in general you want to see the share of strength of each interaction that contributes to a Lagrangian or Hamiltonian to quantify it's relevance. And for this purpose the only choice is a dimensionless coupling constant.

Comment: @enco909 . Thanks for your answer. Could you tell me how you justify the first proportional equality, i.e : $\frac{GM}{R} \propto 1$ ? Regards

Comment: The term is nothing else than the gravitation potential of the universe. I forget to mention that $M$ is the mass and $R$ the radius of the visible universe. Back in the time where this theory was derived the known values of these three constants canceled away each other. I don't revisited it, but I mean to remember that this doesn't hold any more exactly.

Comment: @enco909 . Thanks, I awarded to you the bounty. Just 2 last questions : 1) there are comma in the expression of $\left (\frac {\varphi_ {, i} \varphi ^ {, i}} {\varphi} \right)$ : does it correspond to : $\varphi_ {, i}=\dfrac{\partial \varphi}{\partial \theta_i}$, i.e a derivative as respect of another parameter $\theta_i$ ? 2) Is the Brans-Dicke a main stream modified gravity theory ? and if not, what is the cause or what are the arguments against this theory ? Best regards

Comment: The comma notation in the indices is only a short form of the partial derivative with respect to one of the coordinates.  I'm not too far inside the topic, but as far as I know it's not a really mainstream theory. But it's the prototype of a scalar-tensor theory. Up unitl now it's either proved or disproved and it's violates the SEP principle that states the only effect of gravity is a change in geometry that is itself unproved. But in the limit of large $\omega$ it is proved that this theory leads to general relativity.

Comment: Today such theories are revisited and expanded with the hope to get an explanation for dark energy and dark matter and so to be able to explain the accelerating expansion of the universe, because a physical phenomena that arises only from specific values of an integration constant is pretty unsatisfying.